# Laravel 5.1 - artisan make command

Tags: view, makefile, laravel-5.1

in Laravel 4.2 by using [JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) we could use

```
php artisan generate:view my-view
```

to create a view named my-view.blade.php.

Now in Laravel 5.1 what we should use to generate a view?

```
php artisan make:???
```

Answer (score 0):

According to package's developer, you need to use [L5 version](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) instead. Now you are able to run `php artisan generate:view`.

> As a reminder, these commands are not native of laravel artisan console.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.1 no artisan command for make/generate view.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [sven/artisan-view](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view) package to make view from CMD, to install package write this command:

```bash
composer require sven/artisan-view --dev
```

After installing it, you can make a single view or folder with all views that contain {index-create-update-show}

To make a single file we using this command:

```bash
php artisan make:view  Name_of_view
```

For example

```bash
php artisan make:view index
```

To make a folder that contain all resources **index - create - update - show** write name of folder that contain all this files for example:

```bash
php artisan make:view Name_of_Folder -r
```

For example:

```
php artisan make:view blog -r
```

-r is a shorthand for --resource you can write full name or shorthand to make resource.

For more [view docs](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view)